# Sort dataframe rows according to values in specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
d = {'important1': [1.1, 2.2], 'notimportant1': [1.4, 2.5], 'important2': [3.5, 4.2], 'notimportant2': [1.3,2.0]}
important_lst = ['important1', 'important2']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

I would like to add another column, the sum of the ranks for all columns in `important_lst`.

For example, in the current dataframem,

- the ranks of the first row : 1, 3, 4, 2 so the sum of the ranks will be 5 (1 + 4)
- the ranks of the second row : 2, 3, 4, 1 so the sum of the ranks will be 6 (2 + 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with filtering columns by list, sum and last convert to integers:

```
df['new_col'] = df.rank(axis=1)[important_lst].sum(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
   important1  notimportant1  important2  notimportant2  new_col
0         1.1            1.4         3.5            1.3        5
1         2.2            2.5         4.2            2.0        6
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) on `axis=1`  for determining `rank` across columns  and then and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) on axis=1 after [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter the `important_lst` cols:

```
df['new_col'] = df.rank(1).loc[:,important_lst].sum(1)
print(df)
```

---

```
   important1  notimportant1  important2  notimportant2  new_col
0         1.1            1.4         3.5            1.3      5.0
1         2.2            2.5         4.2            2.0      6.0
```

**Note:** When you sum up float columns , it's better to keep them as floats (5.0 intead of 5) if there is no specific requirement to round them to an integer.